# Android: Executing method from specific thread

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application in Android. The application can post a HTTP request to specific web server. That post request must run asyncronously, so I create a thread to do the job. But I need a callback that will be called at thread end and it must be called from thread that call the `post` method.

My `post` method looks like this:

```
interface EndCallback
{
    public void Success(String response);
    public void Fail(Exception e);
}

public void post(final String url, final List<NameValuePair> data, EndCallback callback)
{
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    (new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            try
            {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
                HttpResponse r = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                HttpEntity en = r.getEntity();
                String response = EntityUtils.toString(en);

                //I want to call callback.Success(response)
                //here from thread t
            } 
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //And I want to call callback.Fail(ex)
                //here from thread t
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: See [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for many options, including a Handler, AsyncTask, or posting Runnable instances to the Activity or View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating new threads an Android is *highly* discouraged for most applications.  This seems like the perfect place for an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It has built-in methods that switch between threads, without needing to manually manage thread creation.

One approach I've used in a similar situation is to combine the task with an `enum` of possible success states:

```
class HttpPostTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ResponseStatus> {

    @Override
    protected ResponseStatus doInBackground( Void... params ){

        try {
            // do your HTTP stuff
            return ResponseStatus.SUCCESS;
        } catch( Exception e ){
            return ResponseStatus.FAILURE;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute( ResponseStatus status ){
        switch( status ){
        case SUCCESS:
            // run your success callback
            break;
        case FAILURE:
            // run the failure callback
            break;
        }
    }

}

enum ResponseStatus {
    SUCCESS,
    FAILURE
}
```

The `doInBackground` method will be run in a separate thread, managed by the OS. When that thread finishes, `onPostExecute` will be run on the thread that started the task, which is typically the UI thread.

If you need to set up callback objects, just add a constructor to the HttpPostTask and do any initialization you need.  Your client code will then just need to create and execute the task:

```
new HttpPostTask().execute();
```

You can also pass parameters into `execute()` as well, which accepts a variable number of arguments of the first generic type in the class signature.  The `params` variable in the `doInBackground` is an array of things that were passed into execute, all of the same type.

Passing params into `execute` is useful if, for example, you wanted to post to multiple URLs. For most dependencies, setting them in the constructor is simplest approach.

Comment: Perfect answer... But, can I pass parameter into `execute()` method? Or I must pass those parameter into constructor?

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan - Yes, and I just updated the end of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use a Handler. Handler is used to post requests to GUI thread.

For success handling, use following code:

```
final Handler successHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message)
    {
        callback.Success(response);
    }
};

successHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```